# SSRS/Oracle - Calculated Field error message: ORA-01747 invalid table.column, table.column, or column specificatio/

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

The SQL query below worked... But when I add the "FreightCostsPerOrderSplit" fields (3 new fields), I get the ORA-01747 error message seen below.  The conventions are similar to what was being done before in the SQL code, and I was unsure what could be causing this error message.

> **Error at line 49** ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column,
>   or column specification

As I was posting this question, I figured out the solution.  I decided to post this answer for others who may come across this same problem.

> The solution involved replacing `COUNT(OHH.*)` with `COUNT(OHH.FieldName)` in the divisor of the calculated fields.  See the answer section for commentary regarding `count(*) vs count(column-name)` syntax.
>
> `, (SUM(cteLoadFreightAgg.TOTALFREIGHT)/ COUNT(OHH.*)) AS "TotalFreight_SplitPerOrder"`

### SQL code (broken at Line 49 with solution posted in answer):

```
    /* A list of aggregated freight carrier data grouped by LOAD (no BILLTOCUST)
    Pulled from [LOAD_CARRIER] table.  Another option is [FRT_LOAD] which include LUMPER
    SOURCE: Loads Underutilize Report
    */
    cteLoadFreightAgg AS
    (
        SELECT
            LOAD_CARRIER.LOAD_SEQ_CODE AS LoadNumber
            , SUM(LOAD_CARRIER.FLAT_FRT + LOAD_CARRIER.FUEL_FRT + LOAD_CARRIER.DROP_FRT + LOAD_CARRIER.MISC_FRT + LOAD_CARRIER.OUT_ROUTE_FRT + LOAD_CARRIER.LAYOVER_FRT) AS TotalFreight
            , SUM(LOAD_CARRIER.DROP_FRT + LOAD_CARRIER.MISC_FRT + LOAD_CARRIER.OUT_ROUTE_FRT + LOAD_CARRIER.LAYOVER_FRT) AS AssessorialsFreight
            , SUM(LOAD_CARRIER.FLAT_FRT) AS FlatRateFreight
            , SUM(LOAD_CARRIER.FUEL_FRT) AS FuelFreight
        FROM
            LOAD_CARRIER
        GROUP BY
            LOAD_CARRIER.LOAD_SEQ_CODE
    )



SELECT
    OHH.BILL_COMP_CODE
    , LOAD.DEPART_FROM_WHSE_CODE
    , OHH.SHIP_FROM_WHSE
    , OHH.ORDER_SEQ_CODE
    , OHH.LOAD_SEQ_CODE
    , OHH.SHIP_DATE
    , CARRIER.NAME AS CarrierName
    , OHH.DELIVERY_DATE
    , CUST.CUST_CODE || '-' || CUST.CUST_SHIPTO_CODE AS ShiptoCustCode
    , CUST.NAME AS ShiptoName
    , OHH.BILL_PO_ID
    , CUST.CITY
    , CUST.STATE_CODE
    , LOAD.TALLY_DATE_TIME
    , OHH.APPT_DATE
    , OHH.APPT_TIME
    , OHH.EST_PALLETS
    , OHH.EST_GROSS_WGT
    , OHH.EST_NET_WGT
    , LOAD.CLASS_CODE
    , SUM(ODH.WEIGHT_SHIPPED) AS "SUM_ODH_WeightShipped"
    -- FreightCostLoad
    , cteLoadFreightAgg.TOTALFREIGHT
    , cteLoadFreightAgg.FUELFREIGHT
    , (cteLoadFreightAgg.TOTALFREIGHT - cteLoadFreightAgg.FUELFREIGHT) AS "OTHERFREIGHT"
    -- FreightCostsPerOrderSplit
    , (SUM(cteLoadFreightAgg.TOTALFREIGHT)/ COUNT(OHH.*)) AS "TotalFreight_SplitPerOrder"
    , (SUM(cteLoadFreightAgg.FUELFREIGHT) / COUNT(OHH.*)) AS "FuelFreight_SplitPerOrder"
    , ((SUM(cteLoadFreightAgg.TOTALFREIGHT) - SUM(cteLoadFreightAgg.FUELFREIGHT))/ COUNT(OHH.*)) AS "OtherFreight_SplitPerOrder"

FROM
    ROCCO.CARRIER CARRIER
    INNER JOIN ROCCO.LOAD_CARRIER LOAD_CARRIER
        ON  CARRIER.CARRIER_CODE = LOAD_CARRIER.CARRIER_CODE
    INNER JOIN ROCCO.ORD_HDR_HST OHH
        ON  LOAD_CARRIER.LOAD_SEQ_CODE = OHH.LOAD_SEQ_CODE
    INNER JOIN ROCCO.ORD_DTL_HST ODH
        ON  OHH.ORDER_SEQ_CODE = ODH.ORDER_SEQ_CODE
    INNER JOIN ROCCO.LOAD LOAD
        ON  OHH.LOAD_SEQ_CODE = LOAD.LOAD_SEQ_CODE
    INNER JOIN ROCCO.CUSTOMER_SHIPTO CUST
        ON  OHH.CUST_CODE = CUST.CUST_CODE
            AND OHH.CUST_SHIPTO_CODE = CUST.CUST_SHIPTO_CODE
    INNER JOIN cteLoadFreightAgg
        ON  LOAD.LOAD_SEQ_CODE = cteLoadFreightAgg.LOADNUMBER
WHERE
--    OHH.SHIP_DATE BETWEEN :paramStartDate AND :paramEndDate
--    AND OHH.STATUS_CODE<>'DL'
--    AND OHH.BILL_COMP_CODE         IN (:paramCompany)
--    AND LOAD.DEPART_FROM_WHSE_CODE IN (:paramWarehouse)
--    AND OHH.MASTER_ORDER_NBR IS NULL
--    AND LOAD.CLASS_CODE                                IN (:paramClassCode)
--    AND CUST.CUST_CODE || '-' || CUST.CUST_SHIPTO_CODE IN (:paramShipto)
--    /*
    OHH.SHIP_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/1/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('10/31/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    AND OHH.STATUS_CODE<>'DL'
    AND OHH.BILL_COMP_CODE=100
    AND OHH.MASTER_ORDER_NBR IS NULL
--    */


GROUP BY
    OHH.BILL_COMP_CODE
    , LOAD.DEPART_FROM_WHSE_CODE
    , OHH.SHIP_FROM_WHSE
    , OHH.ORDER_SEQ_CODE
    , OHH.LOAD_SEQ_CODE
    , OHH.SHIP_DATE
    , CARRIER.NAME
    , OHH.DELIVERY_DATE
    , CUST.CUST_CODE || '-' || CUST.CUST_SHIPTO_CODE
    , CUST.NAME
    , OHH.BILL_PO_ID
    , CUST.CITY
    , CUST.STATE_CODE
    , LOAD.TALLY_DATE_TIME
    , OHH.APPT_DATE
    , OHH.APPT_TIME
    , OHH.EST_PALLETS
    , OHH.EST_GROSS_WGT
    , OHH.EST_NET_WGT
    , LOAD.CLASS_CODE
    , cteLoadFreightAgg.FUELFREIGHT
    , cteLoadFreightAgg.TOTALFREIGHT
ORDER BY
    OHH.SHIP_DATE
                                                      *
Error at line 49
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I had the calculated field as:

`, (SUM(cteLoadFreightAgg.TOTALFREIGHT)/ COUNT(OHH.*)) AS "TotalFreight_SplitPerOrder"`.

For all 3 calculate fields, I changed the divisor field to reference a specific field and the error message was resolved.  Then once that syntaxed parsed successfully, the SSRS report gave a "#VALUE" error message, and I had to use CAST() function to get a proper evaluation instead of an error message in the SSRS report.

`, CAST((cteLoadFreightAgg.TOTALFREIGHT/ COUNT(OHH.ORDER_SEQ_CODE) OVER(PARTITION BY OHH.LOAD_SEQ_CODE)) AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS "TotalFreight_SplitPerOrder"`

So after resolving the original error message, I then figured out I should be doing a WINDOWING function to divide the value as the report requirements dictated.

I did some reading online for an answer to "Why did COUNT(FieldName) evaluate while COUNT(*) gave the error message?".  I came across a few blog articles but they were mostly regarding performance concerns, not row count division or this error message I received.

- https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/countstar-vs-countcolumn-vs-countdistinct-vs-countcol-over/
- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4460/sql-server-count-function-performance-comparison/
- https://www.sqlhammer.com/transact-sql-count-vs-countcolumn-vs-count1/